# Android PackageManager queryIntentActivity need permission

Tags: android

In my App, I want to get all the app installed, code like this

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

when I give the permission of *READ_PHONE_STATE*. I get all the apps, But when I refuse, I get only three app info, it makes me confuse. anyone can explain it. thanks

Comment: What phone is that?

Comment: Huawei Honor 7.

Comment: In Android Studio set logcat filter to "No filter" then execute your code (e.g. on button click) and check logcat for anything suspicious. You're looking for "intent" or "resolve" or "packagemanager" or so.